# Return control to bash script when using /usr/bin/open to close SSH tunnel

Tags: macos, bash, ssh, monterey

I want to write a bash script that:

- establishes an SSH tunnel
- launches a local VNC client (`vncviewer`, the RealVNC viewer in my case)
- closes the SSH tunnel once the `vncviewer` exits

Best effort so far:

```
ssh -L 5900:localhost:5900 <my IP address> -N &
pid=$!
/Applications/VNC\ Viewer.app/Contents/MacOS/vncviewer localhost:5900
kill "$pid"
```

I couldn't get it to work with `open`, though. This works, but the script exits leaving an open tunnel behind:

```
ssh -L 5900:localhost:5900 <my IP address> -N -f sleep 10
open -a 'VNC Viewer' --args localhost:5900
```

Using `open` seems to be more intuitive and user friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man open`:

```
 -W  Causes open to wait until the applications it opens (or that were already open) have exited.
```

So unless **VNC Viewer** is just a launcher, running

```
ssh -L 5900:localhost:5900 <my IP address> -N &
pid=$!
sleep 5
open -W -a 'VNC Viewer' --args localhost:5900
kill "$pid"
```

should do the trick.

Comment: So much of half an hour spent on reading man open :). Thanks a bunch, it works, answer accepted!